# java.lang.NullPonterException when using Graphics.drawImage(image, x, y, ImageObserver)

Tags: image, nullpointerexception, jpanel, bufferedimage, drawimage

I have tried using the ImageIcon way of drawing and image on a panel, I have tried using the ImageIO.read way of drawing, i have build and rebuild multiple projects, and every time i get an error that reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Image_Test.screen.draw(screen.java:41)
    at Image_Test.Basic.run(Basic.java:23)
    at Image_Test.Basic.main(Basic.java:16)
```

screen.java:41 being a line with this exact code:

```
g.drawImage(test, 100, 100, null);
```

I have watched 4 or 5 tutorials on this by different authors, all of which use null for the last argument in this method. Here is a copy of my entire Basic class (has the main method), as well as my screen class (has the drawImage method). These are the only two classes in the project.

```
package Image_Test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Basic
{
    public JFrame window;
    public String title = "The Title for This Window";
    public screen screen = new screen();
    public Graphics g;

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Basic().run(); }

// The run() method is pretty much the main method
    public void run ()
    {
        buildWindow();
        screen.draw(g);
    }

    public void buildWindow ()
    {
        window = new JFrame(title);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        window.add(screen, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        window.setSize(1366, 768);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        window.setLocation(dim.width/2-window.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-window.getSize().height/2);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

---

```
package Full_Game_Test_02;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class screen extends JPanel
{
    public Image Start_Idle;
    public Image Start_Active;
    public Image Exit_Idle;
    public Image Exit_Active;

    Image test = null;

    public screen ()
    {
        test = screen.loadImage("/Start_Active.png");
    }

    public void loadImages ()
    {
        Start_Active = new ImageIcon("C:\\Developing\\Start_Active").getImage();
        Exit_Idle = new ImageIcon("C:\\Developing\\End_Idle").getImage();
        Exit_Active = new ImageIcon("C:\\Developing\\End_Active").getImage();
    }

    public void draw (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(test, 100, 100, null);
    }

    public static Image loadImage (String file)
    {
        Image image = null;

// Exception 1      
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(screen.class.getResource(file));
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception 1");
        }

        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: An easier way of centering your JFrame, is calling `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`, rather than calculating it.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
    screen.draw(g);
```

Doesn't work (`g`is `null` and causing the exception), and further, isn't needed. Neither is your member variable `g`.

If you have a `JPanel` (or subclass, like `Screen`) that is shown on screen in a `JFrame` or similar, Swing will take care of the painting.